# Admin can login as member

Tags: authentication, php

I need to implement new functionality, in that **Admin user** can can login as any **member user** . This functionality I can easily handle using programming.

But the major concern when admin user login as member there would be a button which is call back to Admin login. So how do I handle this using session or any other way because if anyone break the ACL or session It will be create a problem.

**Another Issue**

There may be a possibility admin has some permission restriction when he will login as member.

**Please give me some suggestion on that.**

Comment: Can you clarify what the problem is? Do you have already some idea how to solve your problem? Why do you think anyone can break the ACL? Why does this new functionality create any new problems?

Comment: The problem is how to handle back to admin login and permission restriction for login as member

Comment: This is not a security relevant question, your problem and solution is a programming issue.

Comment: Do you really need it? A mere disconnect/reconnect does the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could store the session privilege level in a stack. When the admin becomes user you push a new token on the stack saying "I'm user now". The "back" function is just a pop from the stack. You could store session tokens in the server session and just delete/reset relevant cookies when someone changes from one level to another.
When going for this approach, be careful with not mixing the access levels. E.g. if admin sessions have a shorter lifetime than ordinary users make sure the admin session is killed in case the "back to admin" happens before the user lifetime ends but after the admin lifetime has ended. There might be tons of other implications, so think thoroughly before taking this into production. One is that in logging and auditing files you might want to log the user's actions for your case as "Somthing done by admin on behalf of user ABC" and not as "Something done by user ABC".